# python split a string by comma not inside matrix expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to split a string separated by commas not inside Matrix expression. 
For example:

input:

```
value = 'MA[1,2],MA[1,3],der(x),x,y'
```

expected output:

```
['MA[1,2]','MA[1,3]','der(x)','x','y']
```

I tried with `value.split(',')`, but it splits inside `[]`, I tried with some regular expressions to catch extract text inside `[]` using this regular expression

```
import re
re.split(r'\[(.*?)\]', value)
```

I am not good in regular expression,Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: I have updated my try, i am not good in regular expression, can we do it any other way without regular expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind

```
>>> import re
>>> value1 = 'MA[1,2],MA[1,3],der(x),x,y'
>>> value2 = 'M[a,b],x1,M[1,2],der(x),y1,y2,der(a,b)'
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(?<![[()][\d\w]),')
>>> pat.split(value1)
['MA[1,2]', 'MA[1,3]', 'der(x)', 'x', 'y']
>>> pat.split(value2)
['M[a,b]', 'x1', 'M[1,2]', 'der(x)', 'y1', 'y2', 'der(a,b)']
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/hH5dS7/4)</kbd>

#### Explanation:

- `"(?<![[()][\d\w]),"g`

  - `(?<![[()][\d\w])` Negative Lookbehind - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below

    - `[[()]` match a single character present in the list below
      `[()` a single character in the list `[()` literally
    - `[\d\w]` match a single character present in the list below
      `\d` match a digit `[0-9]`
      `\w` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

    `,` matches the character , literally

    `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

Comment: Perfect answer, Thank you